# Android: copy sms messages / gallery photos / call history to online resource

Tags: android, copy

I'm developing an Android security project. This project is a sneaky calculator. When an user uses my programmed calculator and presses buttons, there should start background processes which copy's sms messages, gallery photo's and call history from the phone to a source where I can grab these.

But I don't know how I need to start with this. Is it a kind of a backend that I need?

Answer (score 0):

To Read SMS you can use Android provided SMS Manager class. From SMS Manager class you read the SMS's one by one. After each sms read you can dump the data either to your Server or to a local DB.

To know Gallery Photos you can access those from your storage device gallery location.You can read those via FileInputStream and write those file to a server via multipart object type as FileOutputstream object. If you want to store it into Local db you can use it as a Blob object.

To know Call History you can use Android provided CallLog.Calls method.

All the above 3 you can implement one by one in a background Service.